# Changing Pinia state outside of component

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, vuejs3, pinia

I'm trying to implement Pinia in a Nuxt 3/Vue 3 app. I'm using Sidebase for authentication. I have a file to handle the auth in server/api/auth/[...].js and this is where I need to update the Pinia state (after I get the auth token and user info from two api calls).

Based on my console.logs inside the Pinia store, the state IS changing, however, the changes are not reflected on the front end (browser or devtools). It doesn't seem like it's an issue with the state not updating/showing the changes because even after I refresh the page, the state is still not changed.

/server/api/auth/[...].js

```
import { NuxtAuthHandler } from '#auth'
import NextAuth from 'next-auth';
import CredentialsProvider from "next-auth/providers/credentials"
import { useTokenStore } from '~/stores/tokenStore';
import { useUserStore } from '~/stores/userStore';

const config = useRuntimeConfig();
const client_id= config.clientId
const client_secret= config.clientSecret

export default NuxtAuthHandler({
    providers: [
        CredentialsProvider.default({
            // The name to display on the sign in form (e.g. 'Sign in with...')
            name: 'Credentials',
            secret: client_secret,
        
            authorize: async(credentials, req) => {
              const tokenStore = useTokenStore()
              credentials.client_id = client_id
              credentials.client_secret = client_secret
              credentials.grant_type = 'password'
              credentials.scope = '*'
              let user = ''
              try {
                const res = await fetch(`${config.apiBase}/oauth/token`, {
                    method: 'POST',
                    body: JSON.stringify(credentials),
                    headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" }
                })
                const token = await res.json()

                if (res.ok && token) {
                  tokenStore.setToken(token.access_token);
                  const res2 = await fetch(`${config.apiBase}/api/user-info`,{
                    headers: { "authorization": "Bearer " + token.access_token }
                  })
                  user = await res2.json()
                  if (user) {
                    userStore.setUser(user);
                    return user
                  }
                }
              }catch(err){
                console.log(err)
              }
              return null
            },
          })
    ]
})
```

Here's just the one store but neither are updating in the browser:

/stores/tokenStore.js

```
import { defineStore } from 'pinia'

export const useTokenStore = defineStore('tokenStore', {
  state: () => ({
      token: ''
  }),
  actions: {
    setToken(token) {
      this.token = token;
      console.log("in token store", this.token) //this console.log logs the correct info
    },
    removeToken(){
      this.token = ''
    }
  },
})
```

And as you can see here in devtools, no values are being updated.
[image: Devtools screenshot]

Any help would be greatly appreciated!